# fft magnitude scaling

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, magnitude

I use the following code to calculate the fft of 1024 samples of a 200 Hz windowed sinusoid (code taken from aurio touch apple example app):

```
//take fft
vDSP_ctoz((DSPComplex *)input.data(), 2, &inputComplex, 1, mFftSize);
vDSP_fft_zrop(fftSetup, &inputComplex, 1, &output.complex, 1, log2n, FFT_FORWARD);

//scale
float scale = 0.5 / mSize;
vDSP_vsmul(output.complex.realp, 1, &scale, output.complex.realp, 1, mFftSize);
vDSP_vsmul(output.complex.imagp, 1, &scale, output.complex.imagp, 1, mFftSize);
output.complex.imagp[0] = 0.0;

//Convert the fft data to dB
//memset(output.mMagnitude, 0, sizeof(float) * mFftSize);
vDSP_zvmags(&output.complex, 1, output.mMagnitude, 1, mFftSize);

//In order to avoid taking log10 of zero, an adjusting factor is added in to make the minimum value equal -128dB
//memset(output.mDecibel, 0, sizeof(float) * mFftSize);
vDSP_vsadd(output.mMagnitude, 1, &kAdjust0DB, output.mDecibel, 1, mFftSize);
Float32 one = 1;
vDSP_vdbcon(output.mDecibel, 1, &one, output.mDecibel, 1, mFftSize, 0);
```

Taking the inverse fft results in the initial windowed waveform as expected. What's bothering me are the values in output.mMagnitude, I would expect it to be close to 1 at the 200 Hz bin, yet it's barely above 0. What am I missing here?

My windowed sine (1024 samples range -1 to 1 at 200 Hz)
[image]

Magnitude spectrum (512 bins from 0 to 1, all there is is this tiny bump at the 200Hz bin)
[image]

DB spectrum (-128 to 0, this seems appropriate)
[image]

Comment: How is `mSize` defined? Shouldn't it be `mFftSize`?

Comment: @MattL. mSize is 1024 aka the number of samples while mFftSize is 512 aka real and imaginary parts each. I assume the scale value is correct, since the inverse transform returns the same values as were given to the forward transform

Comment: OK. Are the 'DB spectrum' and the 'magnitude spectrum' really based on the same vector `output.mMagnitude`? I guess it can't be the case, because the maximum values are not related by $x_{max}=20\log(y_{max})$, are they?